# How early can you check in your luggage for Amtrak at Washington union station?

Tags: public-transport, luggage-storage, amtrak, washington-dc

I'm arriving into Union station early in the morning, departing at 10pm

I know I can check my luggage for the journey, but can't find an earliest time, the latest is 45 mins.

This was the page that I found that information on

[Amtrak.com checked baggage](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?c=Page&pagename=am%2FLayout&cid=1251621565010)

[Amtrak.com Washington, DC (WAS) Union Station](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?pagename=am/am2Station/Station_Page&code=WAS)

I'm also aware that there is a luggage locker service, located in the station complex but the price per item per hour seemed steep.

Hoping this is an easy answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Amtrak at 800-USA-RAIL, you may check your baggage in as soon as the baggage department opens at the station. It's 7:15AM at my station. Perfect for my 10PM departure.